# Argument 'PeopleController' is not a function, got undefined IonicJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

1. Using IonicJS and rendering some json details.
2. Getting an error: "Argument 'PeopleController' is not a function,
       got undefined"
   I've checked the file 
   *people_controller.js*

(function() {
    var app = angular.module('peopleController',[]);

```
app.controller('PeopleController',
    function($scope, $http) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/people';
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(people) {
    $scope.people = people;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
    console.log('server side error occurred.'); 
    }); 
    } 
    );
    });
```

*app.js:*

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'peopleController'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

*index.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>


    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
   <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
      <ul class="list" ng-controller="PeopleController">
<li class="item" ng-repeat="person in people">
<h3>{{person.name}}</h3>

</li>
</ul>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
     <script src="../js/controllers/people_controller.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**What I am Doing Wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the end was in the **sequence of JS files**, tried loading the app.js file after the peopleController.js but got nothing.

After that just loaded **app.js right after loading peopleController.js and it worked as a charm.**

```
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/people_controller.js"></script>
```

Whole Project Now:

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>

        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
        <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
        -->

        <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->


        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>


        <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>

        <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
          <script src="js/controllers/people_controller.js"></script>
      </head>
       <body ng-app="starter">

        <ion-pane>
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content>
          <ul class="list" ng-controller="PeopleController">
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="person in people">
    <h3>{{person.name}}</h3>

    </li>
    </ul>

          </ion-content>
        </ion-pane>

      </body>
    </html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'peopleController'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

**peopleController.js:**

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('peopleController', []);

app.controller('PeopleController',
function($scope, $http) {
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/people';
$http.get(url)
.success(function(people) {
$scope.people = people;
})
.error(function(data) {
console.log('server side error occurred.'); 
}); 
} 
);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are injecting PeopleController module before this is compiled/inserted in your application. Check sequence of JS files.Load **PeopleController.js** and then **app.js**

Comment: I don't know what happend, tried your thing but nothing worked. After that i tried to load peoplecontroller.js just after app.js and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `peopleController` from module dependenties ==> `angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])`.

It is a controller not a module.

**Edit**

Change `app.controller('PeopleController',...)` 
by `angular.module('starter').controller('PeopleController',...)` too.

Add Angular files and PeopleController.js file as well

```
<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- ionic Dependencies ? -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/PeopleController.js"></script>
```

Comment: forgot to check html... Edited